# How to add a word to a date (year) drop down menu on PHP?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu in my PHP website, that start at 2014, and ends at the current year (2018).

[Drop down menu sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMyGK.png)

I want to add the word: "ACTIVE" to this menu, which will contain all the years together. This option would be selected by default when you open the page. This is the code I have so far for the years.

```
  <?
// Sets the top option to be the current year.
$currently_selected = date('Y');
// Year to start available options at
$earliest_year = 2014;
// Set your latest year you want in the range, in this case, current year
$latest_year = date('Y');


echo "Select year to display: ";
print '<select>';

//Loops over each int[year] from current year, back to $earliest_year [2014]
foreach ( range( $latest_year, $earliest_year ) as $i ) {
    // Prints the option with the next year in range
    print '<option value="'.$i.'"'.($i === $currently_selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    print '</select>';


    ?>
```

How can I add the 'ACTIVE' option?

EDIT**

So, this is what I have right now:

```
<form method="get" action="<?=$this_page?>">

<?



// Sets the top option to be the current year.
$currently_selected = date('Y');
// Year to start available options at
$earliest_year = 2014;
// Set your latest year you want in the range, in this case, current year
$latest_year = date('Y');


echo "Select year to display: ";
print "<select name=\"yearchosen\">";

if(isset($_GET[submitok]))

{

?>
<option value="<?=$yearchosen?>" selected></option>
<?} else {

?>


<option value="Active" selected>Active</option>

<?}

//Loops over each int[year] from current year, back to $earliest_year [2014]
foreach ( range( $latest_year, $earliest_year ) as $i ) {
    // Prints the option with the next year in range
    print '<option value="'.$i.'" >'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    print '</select>';

    ?>

        <td>
        <input style="padding-left:5px" name="submitok" type="submit" value="Update"/>
        </td>

</form>
```

-- When I hit UPDATE, it refreshes the site and I am echoing the selected value, but it doesn't show on the drop down menu.....it shows ACTIVE again.... what am I missing here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is in a html page i would recommend using the alternate sytax for the foreach loop and leaving the html parts as html (without print or echo)

you would simply have to add a

```
<option value="ACTIVE" selected="selected">ACTIVE</option>
```

outside the foreach loop

and you change the existing option within the foreach loop like so:

```
<option value="'.$i.'".'>'.$i.'</option>
```

Comment: thanks, this helped a bit, now I have to figure out how to display the information I want, and probably add a button to send the form....thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So you if you don't want the current year to be selected and want a generic option added to the list you would need to change:

```
print '<option value="'.$i.'"'.($i === $currently_selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</option>';
```

to be

```
print '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
```

And then add in an option just for active after the for loop:

```
print '<option value="active" selected="selected">Active</option>';
```

But your value="active" needs to be replaced with a value that will actually spit back all the years data

Comment: yeah, that is what is confusing me, because with only the years it's easy to have a SWITCH CASE to query only the projects with a specific year, but the change between the word and the years in the drop down menu is what confuses me...

Comment: What is the eventual query / statement that you are running after the selects been made?

Comment: It is a simple query just getting projects under a specific status, but then I add those to an array....not sure how to show the code in this 'comments; section

Answer (score 0):

Because you match integer with string, just put `+` before `$currently_selected` to convert it to integer

```
print '<option value="'.$i.'"'.($i === +$currently_selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</option>';
```